# Power BI: Custom column for client and year

Tags: statistics, analytics, powerbi, powerquery

I want to make a table in the Query Editor (QE) that shows my clients-number, Year, amount and a custom column the indicates whether or not the amount is empty for the last 3 years.

I've tried multiple solutions but none seem to work. I need this in the Query Editor. I can't use a measure for this.

Can someone please help me with this? if any of you need extra information just let me know and I'll see what I can do.

for example what my outcome should be:

`Clientnumber  Year   Amount   Custom table
1             2016   2100        FALSE
1             2017   2000        FALSE
1             2018   100         TRUE

2             2016   0           FALSE
2             2017   100         FALSE
2             2018   3800        FALSE
2             2019   2357        TRUE`

I hope this example helps a bit!

Comment: An example of input and desired output would help a lot. Please see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Dear Alexis Olson I've added an Example of what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I thought of an entirely different method that makes more sense for PQ even if it looks kind of weird. I would think this should run significantly faster.

Make a couple of custom columns that have the Year - 1 and the Year - 2, to get your past two years. Now use the Merge Queries function, and merge the table against itself. Cntrl-Select the Client, then the column you made for Year - 1 in the top table, and Cntrl-Select the Client, then the column for the current Year in the bottom table. Expand out the Amount from the result, but name it Prior Year Amount or whatever. Do the same for the Year -2 column.

[image]

Then just add a custom column that checks for 0 or nulls in the three year amounts, and you have your answer.

[image]

Here's what the final table looked like and the full M code (obviously you can just remove the columns with the prior year/amt references when you're done).

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Client", "Year"},Source,{"Client", "Year"},"Source",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"Source"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "PY", each [Year]-1),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "PPY", each [Year]-2),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom1",{"Client", "PY"},#"Added Custom1",{"Client", "Year"},"Added Custom1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Custom1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Added Custom1", {"Amt"}, {"PY.Amt"}),
    #"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Added Custom1",{"Client", "PPY"},#"Expanded Added Custom1",{"Client", "Year"},"Expanded Added Custom1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Expanded Added Custom1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries2", "Expanded Added Custom1", {"Amt"}, {"PPY.Amt"}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Expanded Added Custom1", "ThreeYearCheck", each not List.ContainsAny({[Amt],[PY.Amt],[PPY.Amt]}, {null, 0})),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Custom2",{{"Client", Order.Ascending}, {"Year", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. so weird that I couldn't find this myself! but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Took a minute to understand what you meant, but I'm operating on the assumption you are looking for if there is an amount in the the year of the record you are looking at as well as each of the prior two years.

I'm also working on the assumption this data is aggregated already, so there is only one amount per client per year (you can easily aggregate this in PQ if that's not already the case).

I don't know if this is the "correct" way to do this, but I'm basically just doing a countifs function. Add a custom column and put this in it (I'm assuming the example you provided as the start point without the custom column, so referencing "Source" as the first step of the query):

```
let CurClient = _[Clientnumber], CurYear = _[Year] in Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Clientnumber] = CurClient and [Year] >= CurYear-2 and [Year] <= CurYear and [Amount] <> 0)) >= 3
```

Comment: Thanks Wedge for this solution. your assumptions where correct! that is exactly what I want. I'll test it out and if it works I will mark this as the answer!

Comment: I have tried the solution you provided and it "Kinda" works. it does give me the result I want but it takes ages to load on the test set of 9 rows. the dataset I want to use it in has over 4000 records. Why is this solution so slow?

Comment: It's running a unique filter on the table for every row to be able be able to count the valid rows, so even if it "works" I don't know if that's practical on the performance end. I feel like there should be a better way since it's incredibly trivial to do in Excel...

Answer (score -1):

**DAX** is what you are looking [**for**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-quickstart-learn-dax-basics).

> use Data Analysis Expressions (DAX) to solve a number of basic calculation and data analysis problems

Comment: Thanks but already tried using DAX, can you maybe help me out with some examples on how to solve my problem. i couldn't find the right answer in DAX and I couldn't find it in M